# Uncaught ReferenceError: bookmarkBar is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am new javascript, and I am currently trying to write my first extension. I have, however, run into a bug I cannot seem to fix. I believe it is something small that I am missing, maybe something syntactical. Here is my code and my manifest file.

```
const lis1 = document.getElementById("newTrain");
lis1.addEventListener("click", createNew);

function createNew() {
    chrome.bookmarks.create({
        parentId: bookmarkBar.id,
        title: getName()
    }, function (newFolder) {
        console.log("added folder: " + newFolder.title);
    });
}

/**
 * Gets the name of the train to be created.
 */
function getName() {
    return prompt("Enter a name for the new train of thought");

}
```

Manifest- I realize some of the permissions are probably not needed here

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Train of thought",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "An extension of the pickup where you left off feature in Chrome.",
  "author": "Derrick Wright",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "bookmarks",
    "declarativeContent",
    "notifications",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Train of thought",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

[image]

EDIT: Here is what I'm currently trying now.

```
const lis1 = document.getElementById("newTrain");
lis1.addEventListener("click", createNew);

function createNew() {
    chrome.bookmarks.create({
        parentId: this.parentId,
        title: getName()
    }, function (newFolder) {
        console.log("added folder: " + newFolder.title);
    });
}
/**
 * Gets the name of the train to be created.
 */
function getName() {
    return prompt("Enter a name for the new train of thought");

}

/**
 * Creates a root folder for extension. Creates folder in bookmarks.
 */
function createRoot() {
    chrome.bookmarks.create({
        parentId: "1", 
        title: 'Train of thought'
    });
}
```

Im trying to assign any new folder to be the children of the root I've created

Comment: bookmarkBar doesn't exist so the code has no idea what bookmarkBar.id is.

Comment: Yeah okay that's pretty obvious I guess. Im am unsure of what to do with the parameter parentId, but this does give me a direction. Thank you

Comment: looks like the parentId should be the name of the parent folder which this bookmark is being added to, something like that. So you could try putting it as the name of your extension.

Comment: Id like to do that but I am not entirely sure how to. I will update my code to show what I am currently trying. I make this root folder I create and assign any new folders made to be its children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the `parentId` parameter since it does not exist while creating a new folder.
The `id` is generated after folder creation.

Use `console.log("Folder id is" +newFolder.id);` to get the id. You will be able to view the created folder in Bookmark Manager ->Other Bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler writes that it cannot find the 'bookmarkBar' where you declared it. It should also have the id property, but since the 'bookmarkBar' not defined, it doesn't have 'id' property